# Weblogic : Even After supplying Custom HostName Verifier---- Still Same SSL Issue

Tags: weblogic11g

Experts !

I had been struggling to make my Webservice Client (using https URL) work within Weblogic Server 10.3.2, which had been causing an issue as below:

*Feb 3, 2012 10:50:28 AM EST Warning Security BEA-090504 Certificate chain received from apcple.XXX.com - 113.128.90.16 failed hostname verification check. Certificate contained apcple.XXX.com but check expected apcple.XXX.com*

If i disable host name verification check using *-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true*  , Code is WORKING fine. No Issue. But that is NOT what is want.

a) I enabled weblogic SSL debugs.

b) I introduced my Custom HostNameVerifier and supplied it via console , I see in the logs that My custom verifier is getting picked up and does Host Name comparison against URL hostname Vs Certiicate CN name and it suceeds and code returns true.

c) If you see SSL debug statements, Connection with server got established  and First time it tries to validate Certificate chain 0 ,1, 2 and LOADS my CUSTOM HostName Verifier.

d) After few lines passed , It again tries to validate Certificates in same Series and SECOND time it DID NOT load My Custome HostName Verifier AND FAILS with the Standard BEA Security Error as pasted above.

Would you please help me to figure out what is missing ?

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

SEE SNIPPET OF SSL DEBUG STATEMENTS

```
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Info WebLogicServer BEA-000307 Exportable key maximum      lifespan set to 500 uses. 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Filtering JSSE SSLSocket
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 SSLIOContextTable.addContext(ctx): 30958379
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 SSLSocket will  be Muxing 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 write SSL_20_RECORD 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 isMuxerActivated: false 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 SSL3/TLS MAC 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 received HANDSHAKE 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 HANDSHAKEMESSAGE: ServerHello 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 HANDSHAKEMESSAGE: Certificate 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Validating certificate 0 in  the chain: Serial number: 1208925819615937499602513
Issuer:O=Cybertrust Inc, CN=Cybertrust Public SureServer SV CA
Subject:C=US, ST=Texas, L=Irving, O=XXX LLC, OU=ns, EMAIL=aes.eng@XXX.com,    CN=apcple.XXX.com
Not Valid Before:Fri Jun 17 10:48:17 EDT 2011
Not Valid After:Sun Jun 17 10:48:17 EDT 2012
Signature Algorithm:SHA1withRSA

Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Validating certificate 1 in the chain: Serial number: 120010508
Issuer:C=IE, O=Baltimore, OU=CyberTrust, CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
Subject:O=Cybertrust Inc, CN=Cybertrust Public SureServer SV CA
Not Valid Before:Wed Sep 08 13:35:16 EDT 2010
Not Valid After:Tue Sep 08 13:34:08 EDT 2020
Signature Algorithm:SHA1withRSA

Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Validating certificate 2 in the chain: Serial number: 33554617
Issuer:C=IE, O=Baltimore, OU=CyberTrust, CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
Subject:C=IE, O=Baltimore, OU=CyberTrust, CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
Not Valid Before:Fri May 12 14:46:00 EDT 2000
Not Valid After:Mon May 12 19:59:00 EDT 2025
Signature Algorithm:SHA1withRSA

Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 validationCallback:   validateErr = 0 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000   cert[0] = Serial number:  1208925819615937499602513
Issuer:O=Cybertrust Inc, CN=Cybertrust Public SureServer SV CA
Subject:C=US, ST=Texas, L=Irving, O=XXX LLC, OU=ns, EMAIL=aes.eng@XXX.com,  CN=apcple.XXX.com
Not Valid Before:Fri Jun 17 10:48:17 EDT 2011
Not Valid After:Sun Jun 17 10:48:17 EDT 2012
Signature Algorithm:SHA1withRSA

Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000   cert[1] = Serial number: 120010508
Issuer:C=IE, O=Baltimore, OU=CyberTrust, CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
Subject:O=Cybertrust Inc, CN=Cybertrust Public SureServer SV CA
Not Valid Before:Wed Sep 08 13:35:16 EDT 2010
Not Valid After:Tue Sep 08 13:34:08 EDT 2020
Signature Algorithm:SHA1withRSA

Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000   cert[2] = Serial number: 33554617
Issuer:C=IE, O=Baltimore, OU=CyberTrust, CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
Subject:C=IE, O=Baltimore, OU=CyberTrust, CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
Not Valid Before:Fri May 12 14:46:00 EDT 2000
Not Valid After:Mon May 12 19:59:00 EDT 2025
Signature Algorithm:SHA1withRSA

Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 weblogic user specified   trustmanager validation status 0 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 SSLTrustValidator returns: 0 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Trust status (0): NONE 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Performing hostname  validation checks: apcple.XXX.com 


############ BELOW  6 LINES INDICATES MY CUSTOM HOST NAME VERIFIER GOT PICKED UP ########
Custom HostName Verifier Called =com.XXX.sys.WeblogicHostNameVerifier
Rcvd. Host Name=apcple.XXX.com SSL Session=javax.net.ssl.impl.SSLSessionImpl@1760238
Parsing COMMON Name from Certificates 
getPeerLeafCert()....Start
Parsed CN = apcple.XXX.com
HOST NAME AND COMMON NAME MATCH FOUND 


Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 HANDSHAKEMESSAGE: ServerHelloDone 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Ignoring not supported JCE  Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacMD5 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacMD5 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacSHA1 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacSHA1 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Will use default Mac for algorithm MD5 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Using JCE Cipher: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm RC4 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacMD5 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacMD5 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacSHA1 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacSHA1 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Using JCE Cipher: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm RSA 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 write HANDSHAKE, offset = 0, length = 262 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 write CHANGE_CIPHER_SPEC, offset = 0, length = 1 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Using JCE Cipher: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm RC4 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HMACMD5 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Will use default Mac for algorithm HMACMD5 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacMD5 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacMD5 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacSHA1 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacSHA1 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 write HANDSHAKE, offset = 0, length = 16 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 isMuxerActivated: false 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 SSL3/TLS MAC 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 received CHANGE_CIPHER_SPEC 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Using JCE Cipher: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm RC4 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HMACMD5 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Will use default Mac for algorithm HMACMD5 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 isMuxerActivated: false 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 SSL3/TLS MAC 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 received HANDSHAKE 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 HANDSHAKEMESSAGE: Finished 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Ignoring not supported JCE  Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacMD5 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacMD5 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Ignoring not supported JCE Mac: SunJCE version 1.6 for algorithm HmacSHA1 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Will use default Mac for algorithm HmacSHA1 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 write APPLICATION_DATA, offset = 0, length = 193 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read(offset=0, length=8192) 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:23 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 isMuxerActivated: false 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:24 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 SSL3/TLS MAC 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:24 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 received APPLICATION_DATA: databufferLen 0, contentLength 143 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:24 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read databufferLen 143 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:24 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read A returns 143 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:24 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read(offset=143, length=8049) 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:24 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 isMuxerActivated: false 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:24 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 SSL3/TLS MAC 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:24 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 received APPLICATION_DATA: databufferLen 0, contentLength 3819 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:24 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read databufferLen 3819 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:24 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read A returns 3819 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:24 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read(offset=3962, length=4230) 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:24 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 isMuxerActivated: false 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:24 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 SSL3/TLS MAC 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:24 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 received APPLICATION_DATA: databufferLen 0, contentLength 8 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:24 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read databufferLen 8 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:24 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read A returns 8 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 write APPLICATION_DATA, offset = 0, length = 193 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read(offset=3970, length=4222) 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 isMuxerActivated: false 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 SSL3/TLS MAC 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 received APPLICATION_DATA: databufferLen 0, contentLength 143 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read databufferLen 143 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read A returns 143 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read(offset=4113, length=4079) 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 isMuxerActivated: false 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 SSL3/TLS MAC 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 received APPLICATION_DATA: databufferLen 0, contentLength 3819 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read databufferLen 3819 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read A returns 3819 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read(offset=7932, length=260) 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 isMuxerActivated: false 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 SSL3/TLS MAC 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 746666 received APPLICATION_DATA: databufferLen 0, contentLength 8 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read databufferLen 8 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 31771821 read A returns 8 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 SSLSetup: loading trusted CA certificates 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Notice Security BEA-090898 Ignoring the trusted CA  certificate "CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 3,OU=T-Systems Trust Center,O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH,C=DE". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11. 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Notice Security BEA-090898 Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 2,OU=T-Systems Trust Center,O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH,C=DE". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11. 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 clientInfo has HostnameVerifier 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Filtering JSSE SSLSocket 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 SSLIOContextTable.addContext(ctx): 25583909 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 SSLSocket will  be Muxing 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 write SSL_20_RECORD 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 isMuxerActivated: false 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 28097422 SSL3/TLS MAC 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 28097422 received HANDSHAKE 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 HANDSHAKEMESSAGE: ServerHello 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 HANDSHAKEMESSAGE: Certificate 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Validating certificate 0 in  the chain: Serial number: 1208925819615937499602513
Issuer:O=Cybertrust Inc, CN=Cybertrust Public SureServer SV CA
Subject:C=US, ST=Texas, L=Irving, O=XXX LLC, OU=ns, EMAIL=aes.eng@XXX.com,   CN=apcple.XXX.com
Not Valid Before:Fri Jun 17 10:48:17 EDT 2011
Not Valid After:Sun Jun 17 10:48:17 EDT 2012
Signature Algorithm:SHA1withRSA

Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Validating certificate 1 in  the chain: Serial number: 120010508
Issuer:C=IE, O=Baltimore, OU=CyberTrust, CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
Subject:O=Cybertrust Inc, CN=Cybertrust Public SureServer SV CA
Not Valid Before:Wed Sep 08 13:35:16 EDT 2010
Not Valid After:Tue Sep 08 13:34:08 EDT 2020
Signature Algorithm:SHA1withRSA

Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Validating certificate 2 in  the chain: Serial number: 33554617
Issuer:C=IE, O=Baltimore, OU=CyberTrust, CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
Subject:C=IE, O=Baltimore, OU=CyberTrust, CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
Not Valid Before:Fri May 12 14:46:00 EDT 2000
Not Valid After:Mon May 12 19:59:00 EDT 2025
Signature Algorithm:SHA1withRSA

Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 validationCallback: validateErr = 0 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000   cert[0] = Serial number: 1208925819615937499602513
Issuer:O=Cybertrust Inc, CN=Cybertrust Public SureServer SV CA
Subject:C=US, ST=Texas, L=Irving, O=XXX LLC, OU=ns, EMAIL=aes.eng@XXX.com,     CN=apcple.XXX.com
Not Valid Before:Fri Jun 17 10:48:17 EDT 2011
Not Valid After:Sun Jun 17 10:48:17 EDT 2012
Signature Algorithm:SHA1withRSA

Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000   cert[1] = Serial number: 120010508
Issuer:C=IE, O=Baltimore, OU=CyberTrust, CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
Subject:O=Cybertrust Inc, CN=Cybertrust Public SureServer SV CA
Not Valid Before:Wed Sep 08 13:35:16 EDT 2010
Not Valid After:Tue Sep 08 13:34:08 EDT 2020
Signature Algorithm:SHA1withRSA

Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000   cert[2] = Serial number: 33554617
Issuer:C=IE, O=Baltimore, OU=CyberTrust, CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
Subject:C=IE, O=Baltimore, OU=CyberTrust, CN=Baltimore CyberTrust Root
Not Valid Before:Fri May 12 14:46:00 EDT 2000
Not Valid After:Mon May 12 19:59:00 EDT 2025
Signature Algorithm:SHA1withRSA

Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 weblogic user specified trustmanager validation status 0 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 SSLTrustValidator returns: 0 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Trust status (0): NONE 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Performing hostname validation checks: apcple.XXX.com 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Warning Security BEA-090504 Certificate chain received  from apcple.XXX.com - 113.128.90.16 failed hostname verification check. Certificate contained apcple.XXX.com but check expected apcple.XXX.com 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 Hostname Verification failed for certificate with CommonName 'apcple.XXX.com' against hostname: apcple.XXX.com 
Feb 3, 2012 10:50:25 AM EST Debug SecuritySSL BEA-000000 NEW ALERT with Severity: FATAL, Type: 42
java.lang.Exception: New alert stack
at com.certicom.tls.record.alert.Alert.init(Unknown Source)
at com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.HandshakeHandler.fireAlert(Unknown Source)
at com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.ClientStateReceivedServerHello.handle (Unknown Source)
at com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.HandshakeHandler.handleHandshakeMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.HandshakeHandler.handleHandshakeMessages(Unknown Source)
at com.certicom.tls.record.MessageInterpreter.interpretContent(Unknown Source)
at com.certicom.tls.record.MessageInterpreter.decryptMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.processRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readUntilHandshakeComplete(Unknown Source)
at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.completeHandshake(Unknown  Source)
at com.certicom.tls.record.WriteHandler.write(Unknown Source)
at com.certicom.io.OutputSSLIOStreamWrapper.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:123)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:158)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:363)
at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream (SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:37)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:952)
at  com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage (HttpClientTransport.java:213)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process (HttpTransportPipe.java:172)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest (HttpTransportPipe.java:101)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:604)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:563)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:548)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:445)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:248)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:135)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:118)
at $Proxy189.updateMilestone(Unknown Source)
at com.XXX.sys.apc.APCProcessor.updateMilestoneToApc(APCProcessor.java:95)
at com.XXX.sys.apc.APCProcessor.sendAsrFeed(APCProcessor.java:50)
at com.XXX.sys.apc.APCLookupBean.onMessage(APCLookupBean.java:94)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at  com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection     (AopUtils.java:310)
at  com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoin     point(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
at   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed        (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke     (ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed        (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at    com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doPro     ceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at   com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invok     e(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed        (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke   (JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy148.onMessage(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:466)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage  (MDListener.java:371)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:327)
at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:4585)
at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:4271)
at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.executeMessage(JMSSession.java:3747)
at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.access$000(JMSSession.java:114)
at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession$UseForRunnable.run(JMSSession.java:5096)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)'
```

Comment: Any Help Please ? I tried all the approaches but no luck.